# Duplicates issue

Tags: duplicates, sas

I have a problem with duplicates. 
Actually what I need is only the see duplicates but my table has many variables something like the below:

```
 a     b    c    d     e
32    ayi  dam  som   kem
32    ayi  dam  som   tws
32    ayi  dam  tsm   tws
12    mm   ds    de   ko
12    mm   tmm  to    ko
```

I am trying to keep if 'a' 'b' 'c' and 'd' variables are same. So I need only first 2 columns. I try to do this

```
 proc sort data=al nodupkey dupout=dups; 
 by a  b  c  d; 
 run;
```

any idea if this works?

Comment: You need the first two rows, not the first two columns.  Have you tried the above?

Comment: Yes, I tried but don't work

Comment: Then can you put that in the question and what error you got and/or what you mean  by didn't work?

Comment: ok. I am trying to create a table if a, b, c and d variables are same. So I need to keep first 2 rows. When I use this code it gives me only second row not  the first one.

Comment: my question is: How can I keep duplicates in a table? But based on more than one variable needs to be same

Comment: Please edit that into the question rather than in comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option could be Proc SQL, no pre-sort needed:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select * from have
group by a, b, c, d
having count(*)>1; /*This is to tell SAS only to keep those dups*/
quit;
```

Answer (score 2):

In SAS 9.3+ you can do this very easily with the new `nouniquekey` option.

```
proc sort data=have nouniquekey out=want;
  by a b c d;
run;
```

That removes any rows which are unique and leaves duplicates.

If you have an earlier version of SAS, you can do something fairly simple after a regular sort.

So, after sorting as in your example above but without nodupkey:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by a b c d;
  if not (first.d and last.d);
run;
```

That removes records that are the first AND last record based on `a b c d`.